# How to assign value to lookup field without writing code

Tags: trigger, formula, workflow, process-builder, formula-field

There are 2 custom objects. There is a lookup field in child object which contains pre populated reference value to parent object. Is there any way to populate lookup value in child object with "text" type field value of parent object without writing code?

The requirement is to change the default value of lookup field.

Comment: Lookup relationships reference the Name field (e.g Contact to Account) for the related SObject. It might be best if you elaborate further on what the current issue with your standard/custom lookup field is before the community assist with a solution or path forward.

Comment: @TSmith updated the question. The requirement is to pull the text field from parent object (which can be done via formula field) but also update the lookup field value with the pulled text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking to pull a text field from a parent record into its child record. The way to achieve this is creating a text formula field on the the child object. This field will exist beside the lookup field to the parent record.

Comment: EranV its correct that i need to pull text value from parent object to child object and i can do it via formula field but how shall i populate lookup field on child object with the pulled text?

Comment: You don't populate the lookup field with that text, the lookup is intended to contain only a pointer to the ID of the parent and establish the association between the parent and the child. Any other information should be contained in a different field, such as the formula field discussed.

Comment: The requirement is to put the value of pulled text in the lookup field not in a separate field

Comment: Then the requirement was made by someone who doesn't fully understand how Salesforce data structure works. The lookup field can keep only the parent ID, which renders in the UI to a friendly presentation of the parent record name. There's no way to populate any other type of data in a lookup field.

Comment: stumbled upon this https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000337963&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1 . Doesn't this point that we can update the lookup field ? Please suggest

Comment: Yes, it does. It explains how to leverage process builder to automatically update a lookup field with another record's ID reference, so that it becomes its parent. Record ID reference is the only thing you can populate in a lookup field.